# Unable to segregate comments with their respective answers

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have seen the solution to my problem in form and tried using the nested `ng-repeat`. My project consists of a question and their related answers, each answer consists of comments. While using nested `ng-repeat` I am able to print the same comment array for each question.
Result array:

[image]

I have tried this :

```
 <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1" ng-repeat="x in question.answercomments track by $index">
        <div ng-repeat="y in x">
                {{y.comment}}
        </div>

</div>
```

and ended up with:

[image]

So, I want to have comments on their respective answers.

Comment: It is hard to understand the data and how it is structured in your example. Can you create a jsfiddle with an example if the data and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt to solve this issue:  https://plnkr.co/edit/UrjCzU4ocBxwFNwcVedU

You can try the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.answer">
  <h1 ng-bind-html="answer.answer"></h1>
  <!-- loop over the comments attached to this particular answer -->
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1" ng-repeat="x in answer.answercomments"> 
    <!-- now output the comment -->
    {{x.comment}}
  </div>
</div>
```

---

the issue, I think, was that you weren't looping over the comments attached to a particular answer and then outputting the comments

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not looping over comments attached to the particular answer. I was looping again from the beginning inside the loop.